# Aggregate only successive rows in data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table with roughly 30 columns and 100 million rows. The data contain several blocks of rows where each row in a block has the same value in three particular columns I am interested in. Here is an illustrative example where the columns I am interested in are Time, Fruit, and Colour:

```
dt <- data.table(Time = c(100, rep(101, 4), rep(102, 2), 103:105), 
                   Ref = 1:10, 
                   Fruit = c(rep('banana', 2), 'apple', rep('banana', 2), 
                             rep('orange', 2), 'banana', rep('apple', 2)), 
                   Colour = c('green', 'yellow', 'red', rep('yellow', 2), 
                              rep('blue', 2), 'red', 'green', 'red'), 
                   Price = c(rep(1, 3), 2, 4, 3, 1, rep(5, 3)))
dt

#    Time Ref  Fruit Colour Price
# 1:  100   1 banana  green     1
# 2:  101   2 banana yellow     1
# 3:  101   3  apple    red     1
# 4:  101   4 banana yellow     2
# 5:  101   5 banana yellow     4
# 6:  102   6 orange   blue     3
# 7:  102   7 orange   blue     1
# 8:  103   8 banana    red     5
# 9:  104   9  apple  green     5
#10:  105  10  apple    red     5
```

This example contains two blocks. The first consists of the `101-banana-yellow` rows 4 and 5, and the second consists of the `102-orange-blue` rows 6 and 7. Note that even though row 2 matches rows 4 and 5 on Time, Fruit, and Colour, I do not want to include it as part of a block since row 3 is different from 2, 4, and 5, and breaks the chain of successive, matching rows.

Once I have found these blocks I want to combine the blocks in such a way that for most columns only the value from the last row in the block remains, while for other columns I want to sum up the values in all rows. In this example Ref should display the last value while Price should sum up, so my desired output is:

```
#    Time Ref  Fruit Colour Price
# 1:  100   1 banana  green     1
# 2:  101   2 banana yellow     1
# 3:  101   3  apple    red     1
# 4:  101   5 banana yellow     6
# 5:  102   7 orange   blue     4
# 6:  103   8 banana    red     5
# 7:  104   9  apple  green     5
# 8:  105  10  apple    red     5
```

I tried doing this with data.table's `by` feature, but I can't get the desired output:

```
byMethod <- dt[, list(Ref = tail(Ref, 1), Price = sum(Price)), by = list(Time, Fruit, Colour)]
setcolorder(byMethod, c('Time', 'Ref', 'Fruit', 'Colour', 'Price'))
byMethod

#    Time Ref  Fruit Colour Price
# 1:  100   1 banana  green     1
# 2:  101   5 banana yellow     7
# 3:  101   3  apple    red     1
# 4:  102   7 orange   blue     4
# 5:  103   8 banana    red     5
# 6:  104   9  apple  green     5
# 7 :  105  10  apple    red     5
```

This works fine with the `102-orange-blue` block in the example, but it doesn't produce the result I want for the `101-banana-yellow` block because it includes row 2 in this block when I don't want to.

Can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is this fast enough?

```
#create an index
dt[,i:=.I]
#group adjacent indices together
dt[, g:=cumsum(c(1, (diff(i) > 1))), by=list(Time, Fruit, Colour)]
#sum prices
dt[, list(Ref=tail(Ref, 1), Price=sum(Price)), 
   by=list(Time, Fruit, Colour, g)]

#    Time  Fruit Colour g Ref Price
# 1:  100 banana  green 1   1     1
# 2:  101 banana yellow 1   2     1
# 3:  101  apple    red 1   3     1
# 4:  101 banana yellow 2   5     6
# 5:  102 orange   blue 1   7     4
# 6:  103 banana    red 1   8     5
# 7:  104  apple  green 1   9     5
# 8:  105  apple    red 1  10     5
```

Answer (score 3):

`rleid()` is now implemented in [1.9.5](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/commit/b8c1b01ac9453750d0e99a388522877eec38f06b), see [#686](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/686). . From [NEWS](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/blob/master/README.md):

> 7) `rleid()`, a convenience function for generating a run-length type id column to be used in grouping operations is now implemented. Closes [#686](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/686). Check `?rleid` examples section for usage scenarios.

With this we can now do:

```
require(data.table) ## 1.9.5+
dt[, rleid := rleid(Time, Fruit, Colour)]
dt[, .(Ref = Ref[.N], Price = sum(Price)), by=.(Time, Fruit, Colour, rleid)]
```

Comment: I get `Error in rleidv(list(...)) : Type 'list' not supported` when running this in `v1.9.7`. Should it be `dt[, rleid := rleid(Time, Fruit, Colour)]` ?